# how to play real time media on a webpage?

Tags: html, streaming, real-time, media

I am a bit confused in finding out a solution for my project.

My objective : To play real time audio/video on a webpage

What I am currently Doing:

1. I setup an XAMPP server
2. I setup the Windows Media Encorder and broadcasted the live stream
3. I can see the streaming in windows media player but I want to put it in my webpage.

What I want to know?
 1. I tried to use the html video tag and tried to put the source as my link to streaming mms://myip:myport.
 2. But it does not work.
 3. I found some articles to embed the windows media player into webpage but that works for Firefox and Internet explorer. I need to work this on chrome also.

Following are my questions

1. Is it possible to embedd an real time media stream in html video
   tag?
2. Do you know any tool like Windows Media Encorder which is
   universal and not microsoft      specific which will run on all
   browsers?
3. Is it possible to do in some java , can anybody suggest
   some code?
4. Or if you can suggest some other tools or methods to
   accomplish my objective, I will be so much grateful.

Thanks you friends. I will be waiting for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just try following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/i.js"></script></BODY></HTML>
<table border='0' cellpadding='0' align="left">
<tr><td>
<OBJECT id='mediaPlayer' width="320" height="285"
classid='CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95'
codebase='http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701'
standby='Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components...' type='application/x-oleobject'>
 <param name='fileName' value="http://www.freewebs.com/hxrzclan/stl.WMA">
<param name='animationatStart' value='true'>
<param name='transparentatStart' value='true'>
<param name='autoStart' value="true">
<param name='showControls' value="true">
<param name='loop' value="true">
<EMBED type='application/x-mplayer2'
pluginspage='http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/'
id='mediaPlayer' name='mediaPlayer' displaysize='4' autosize='-1'
bgcolor='darkblue' showcontrols="true" showtracker='-1'
showdisplay='0' showstatusbar='-1' videoborder3d='-1' width="320" height="285"
src="http://www.freewebs.com/hxrzclan/stl.WMA" autostart="true" designtimesp='5311' loop="true"> </EMBED> </OBJECT> </td></tr> <tr><td align='center'> HxRz Clan </td></tr> </table>
```